# Hive partition and new attribute introduction after table is created

Tags: hadoop, hive

This is related to Apache Hive partition issue.

Please help me out on new attribute addition after a partition table is created.
New attribute data is not loading.

Is there anything we need to tweak?

**Data:**

```
header: id,  name, date,   sal

dummy.txt
---------

1,Narayana,20150201,20.345
2,Narayana1,20150202,23.654
3,Narayana2,20150203,776.23
4,Narayana3,20150204,23.224
5,Narayana4,20150205,77.88
6,Narayana5,20150206,99.765
```

**DDL**

```
create schema nari;
use nari;

drop table x_1;
create external table x_1(
  id int
 ,name string
 ,dt string
 ,sal double)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION '/user/hdpcsc/data';

drop table p_emp;
create table p_emp(
  id int
 ,name string
 ,dt string)
partitioned by(fp string)
CLUSTERED BY (id) SORTED BY (id asc) INTO 256 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

**insert1**

```
insert overwrite table  p_emp partition(fp="Q1FY15")
select id, name, dt from x_1;
```

**select**

```
select * from p_emp; -- works well
```

**insert2**

```
insert overwrite table  p_emp partition(fp="FCQ116")
select id, name, dt from x_1;
```

**select**

```
select * from p_emp; -- works well
```

**Now add new attribute**

```
alter table p_emp add columns (sal double);
```

**insert4**

```
insert overwrite table  p_emp partition(fp="Q1FY15")
select id, name, dt, sal from x_1;
```

**select**

```
select * from p_emp; -- sal attr null data
```

**insert5**

```
insert overwrite table  p_emp partition(fp="FCQ116")
select id, name, dt, sal from x_1;
```

**select**

```
select * from p_emp; -- sal attr null data
```

Comment: are you getting the salary values when you select from the normal table x_1 ?

Comment: yes , i got values `hive (nari)> select * from x_1;
OK
x_1.id  x_1.name        x_1.dt  x_1.sal
1       Narayana        20150201        20.345
2       Narayana1       20150202        23.654
3       Narayana2       20150203        776.23
4       Narayana3       20150204        23.224
5       Narayana4       20150205        77.88
6       Narayana5       20150206        99.765
Time taken: 0.068 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below queries for adding the columns and execute the insert if using hive0.14.0:

```
alter table p_emp partition(fp="Q1FY15") add columns (sal double);
alter table p_emp partition(fp="FCQ116") add columns (sal double);
```

The issue you are facing is an bug(HIVE- 6131) in hive in  0.11.0,0.12.0 and 0.13.0 versions.

If you are getting error when executing the above alter statements then try dropping the partitions and insert the data again. hope this helps....

Comment: partition clause will be available from hive0.14.0 and later